# BUGCODE_USB_DRIVER installing windows server 2008 r2

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, bsod

I am trying to install windows server 2008 r2 onto my server which is hp prolient dl380 g5. i first use the hp smart disk followed by the windows cd every time i get near the end of the windows installation i get a blue screen saying BUGCODE_USB_DRIVER then the server restarts and my installation cannot complete. i have tried to install other server operating systems but i get the same error ever time no matter what i try and install. i also created a smart cd with ilo firmware update and a controller firmware update but still get the same errors and now i am out of ideas can anybody please help

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirely sure what function you're using SmartStart for but my general sequence when building by hand is;

- Boot from [LATEST](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=uk&prodTypeId=15351&prodSeriesId=1121516&prodNameId=3288134&swEnvOID=4064&swLang=8&mode=2&taskId=135&swItem=MTX-8d8870eebb4244918bd75303f4) SmartStart and update all firmware
- Install base generic W2K8R2 code
- Install [LATEST](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=uk&prodTypeId=15351&prodSeriesId=1121516&prodNameId=3288134&swEnvOID=4064&swLang=8&mode=2&taskId=135&swItem=MTX-79b1f86e0dc945c5bc2359f08a) Proliant Support Pack

If you're following this flow and don't have anything odd plugged into your USB ports yet still see the same problems then I suggest you place a call with HP directly as you may have a faulty systemboard that needs work.

Comment: what is the w2k8r2 code?

Comment: Sorry, Windows Server 2008 R2, just a shortening of the name :)

Comment: how do i make the proliant support pack bootable

Comment: You don't - it's not, you simply mount it after the base OS install (if you can get that far). The SmartStart is bootable though.

Comment: ye i cant seem to get past the installation without it bsod. and hp say they dont no what to do as they have gone though there steps with me

Comment: They can send an engineer out with a new systemboard surely? are you installing from a regular DVD or something else?

Comment: i got microsoft action pack so i downloaded it off the microsoft site and burned it to a cd

Comment: Is this on an otherwise entirely blank/wiped system or an upgrade? either way I'd be tempted to get HP to swap out the systemboard.

Comment: we had it as a citrix server on there before then there was a fatel error and we had to wipe it and thohght we would take opertunity to upgrade it to a 2008 server

Comment: ok, so it's blank, great, still think you need to check your USB ports, maybe try another DVD from a different source and if you still have problems get HP to fix the systemboard ok.

Answer (score 0):

For those still tinkering around or using server 2008 R2 SP1 for production servers. This is also a valid solution.

http://www.sevenforums.com/crash-lockup-debug-how/175994-solution-fo-bugcode_usb_driver-bsod.html

It appears that the windows SP1 uses a slightly different binary driver file for the USB controller. Hence the BSOD telling you there is something wrong with your system.

The MS update to address the issue [Article ID: 2529073](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2529073)

Comment: What also can help is too upgrade the ILO firmware. In my case for my DL380G5 it was still flashed on 1.26. Now it's running the 2.26 firmware.

Comment: Yep… It was the ILO firmware…

Answer (score -1):

i Got the Solution Of bug-code_USB_driver Error
Go to BIOS Setting And Disable USB controller And Install Again It Works 
and when installation is complete again Enable The USB controller